# The screen changes according to the scroll value

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, gsap

`How can I make the contents and animations of .sec2 work at that time as the first section, .sec1, is gradually covered in navy color according to the scroll value, and then slowly changes to a white background to move to the second section, .sec2? ?

--------------------index.html----------------------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>ramp main page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../styles/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <script src="../../jquery/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../jquery/jquery_3.6.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.1/ScrollToPlugin.min.js">              </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.1/EasePack.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main id="main" class="main">
    <article id="container" class="container">
      <section class="sec1" id="color_overlay">
        <div class="bannerWrap">
          <div class="banner">
            <div class="banner_txt">
              <h2 class="text">Connecting dreams,<br> empowering futures<br> with "RAMP"</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="ohro"></div>
            <div class="sun1">
              <img src="../../assets/images/aset1.png" alt="선1">
            </div>
            <div class="sun2">
              <img src="../../assets/images/aset2.svg" alt="선2">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>


      <section class="sec2">
        <div class="logoWrap">
          <div class="logo">
            <div class="unlock">
              <h3 class="text2">Unlock your potential through education</h3>
            </div>
            <img src="../../assets/icons/rampLogo.png" alt="로고">
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

-----------------main.css----------------------------------------------------------

```
body{
    height: auto;
}
/* #scroll_content{
    height: 4000px;
}

#color_overlay{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
} */
/* Main CSS */
.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}

.sec1,
.sec2 {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sec1{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 128, 0); /* 초기 투명 상태 */
    transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out; /* 색상 전환 애니메이션 설정 */
    height: 200vh;
}

.container .bannerWrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    z-index: -1;
}

.banner_txt {
    position: relative;
    left: 25%;
    top: 25%;
    color: white;
    z-index: 2;
}

.text {
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-top: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    /* 초기에 투명하게 설정 */
    animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in-out forwards;
    /* fade-in 애니메이션 적용 */
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(20px);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

.sun1,
.sun2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20%;
    right: -20%;
    z-index: 1;
    animation: rotateSun linear infinite;
}

.sun1 img,
.sun2 img {
    width: 1300px;
    animation: floatSun linear infinite;
}

.ohro {
    width: 120%;
    height: 200%;
    position: absolute;
    background: url(../../assets/images/ohro2.jpeg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    top: 0;
    /* 초기 위치를 상단에 설정 */
    left: -20%;
    z-index: 0;
    /* 앞으로 bring to front */
}

/* sec2 */

.sec1 {
    height: 100vh;
}

.sec2 {
    height: 100vh;
    /* display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center; */
}

.logoWrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .logoWrap {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  
  .logo img{
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
  }
  
  .unlock .text2 {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out, transform 1s ease-in-out;
    color: navy;
    font-size: 70px;
    white-space: nowrap;

  }
  
  
  .unlocked {
    opacity: 1; /* 애니메이션 이후에 투명도 1로 설정 */
    transform: translateY(0); /* 애니메이션 이후에 위치를 원래 위치로 설정 */
  }
```

--------------------------main.js---------------------------------------

```
$(function () {

    // --------- 4chawon ---------------
    var sun1Position = 0;
    var sun2Position = 0;
    var sun1Speed = 0.003; // sun1의 움직이는 속도
    var sun2Speed = 0.005; // sun2의 움직이는 속도
    var isMoving = true; // 이동 여부

    function moveSun() {
        if (isMoving) {
            sun1Position -= sun1Speed;
            sun2Position -= sun2Speed;

            $(".sun1").css("transform", "translateX(" + sun1Position + "%)");
            $(".sun2").css("transform", "translateX(" + sun2Position + "%)");

            requestAnimationFrame(moveSun);
        }
    }

    function stopSun() {
        isMoving = false;
    }

    moveSun();

    // 일정 시간 후에 멈춤 상태로 변경
    setTimeout(stopSun, 10000); // 10초 후에 멈춤 상태로 변경




    // ---------------ohrora-------------------
    var ohroPosition = 0;
    var ohroSpeed = 0.2; // ohro의 움직이는 속도
    var isMoving = true;

    function moveOhro() {
        if (isMoving) {
            ohroPosition -= ohroSpeed;

            $(".ohro").css("transform", "translateY(" + ohroPosition + "px)");

            requestAnimationFrame(moveOhro);
        }
    }

    moveOhro();

    setTimeout(function () {
        isMoving = false;
    }, 10000);


    // -----------------logo floating -------------------
    // 로고 요소를 선언합니다.
    var logoElement = $(".logoWrap");
    $('.unlock').css('opacity', 0);

    // ScrollTrigger를 사용하여 스크롤 애니메이션을 설정합니다.
    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
  
    gsap.set('.logoWrap', {
        scale: 4,
        duration : 4
    
      });
      
      gsap.to('.logoWrap', {
        scale: 0.1,
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: '.sec2',
          start: 'top center',
          end: 'bottom center',
          scrub: true,
          // .logoWrap 애니메이션이 끝나면 .unlock 텍스트에 fade-in 효과를 줍니다.
          onToggle: (self) => {
            if (self.isActive) {
              gsap.fromTo('.unlock', {
                opacity: 0,
                y: 50
              }, {
                opacity: 1,
                y: 0,
                duration: 1,
                delay: 1,
                onComplete: function () {
                  $('.unlock .text2').addClass('unlocked');
                }
              });
            }
          }
        }
      });
      



});
```

---------------  main.js test-----------------------

```
// ScrollTrigger 플러그인 등록
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

// .sec1 배경 색상 애니메이션
gsap.to(".sec1", {
    backgroundColor: "navy",
    ease: "none",
    scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ".sec1",
        start: "top top",
        end: "bottom top",
        scrub: true
    }
});

// .sec2 투명도 애니메이션
gsap.to(".sec2", {
    opacity: 0,
    ease: "none",
    scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ".sec2",
        start: "top center",
        end: "bottom center",
        scrub: true
    }
});

// .logo 이미지 애니메이션
gsap.set(".logo img", { scale: 1 }); // 초기 크기 설정

gsap.to(".logo img", {
    scale: 1.2,
    scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ".sec2",
        start: "top center",
        end: "bottom center",
        scrub: true
    }
});

// .unlock 텍스트 애니메이션
gsap.set(".unlock .text2", { opacity: 0, y: 50 }); // 초기 상태 설정

gsap.to(".unlock .text2", {
    opacity: 1,
    y: 0,
    duration: 1,
    delay: 1,
    scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ".sec2",
        start: "top center",
        end: "bottom center",
        scrub: true
    },
    onComplete: function() {
        $('.unlock .text2').addClass('unlocked');
    }
});
```

-------------------------------------------test end ----------

Depending on the user's scroll value, the image or text under .sec1 is slowly covered in navy color to the extent that it is invisible, and when it is completely covered, it moves to .sec2 and is slowly covered in navy color, the opacity approaches 0,
The image of the .logo is placed so large that it does not fill the screen size, and then it is placed small enough to fit the center of the user's screen at the same speed as the opacity approaches 0.
And when the logo image is placed in the center and made small, and opacity approaches 0,
As the text inside .unlock fades in, I expected an animation that seemed to float above the hidden object under the logo image.

However, the sections don't flow naturally, they don't feel connected to .sec1 and .sec2, and they don't turn navy.
`